# React PUT and GET axios request in 1 function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have 2 custom hooks. 1 to PUT data, the other to GET the data. I need to retrieve the data immediately after it has been PUT to route the user and handle any errors. With what I have below, the actions happen to fast and GET happens before PUT. Any way around this?

```
    const { update, fetch, data, loading, success } = useFoo(data);

    const OnClickHandler = () => {
        update();

        if (success === 200) {
            fetch();
          // do some checks and if ok route
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    };
  



 const fetch = useCallback(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios({
            url: url,
            headers: foo,
            method: "get"
        })
            .then((response) => {
                setLoading(false);
                setSuccess(response.status);
                setData(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, [setSuccess]);

    const update = useCallback(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios({
            url: url,
            headers: foo,
            method: "put",
            data: data,
            responseType: "json"
        })
            .then((response) => {
                setLoading(false);
                setSuccess(response.status);
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, [data]);
```

Comment: Use `await update();`..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to wait for the end of certain calls, you must mark the function as async and wait for the function call.

I tried to anticipate the structure of your **useFoo()** hook, and here are my changes:

```js
const useFoo = (data) => {
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = React.useState(false)
  const [ success, setSuccess ] = React.useState()
  const [ data, setData ] = React.useState()
  const [ error, setError ] = React.useState()

  const fetch = React.useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true)

    await axios({
      url, // TODO: pass your url
      headers: {}, // TODO: pass your headers
      method: 'get'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setSuccess(response.status)
        setData(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error)
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }, [ setSuccess ])

  const update = React.useCallback(
    async () => {
      setLoading(true)

      await axios({
        url, // TODO: pass your url
        headers: {}, // TODO: pass your headers
        method: 'put',
        data,
        responseType: 'json'
      })
        .then((response) => {
          setSuccess(response.status)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(error)
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    },
    [ data ]
  )

  return {
    data,
    fetch,
    loading,
    success,
    update,
    error
  }
}
```

The component that uses the hook might look something like this:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  const { update, fetch, data, success } = useFoo(foo)

  const onClickHandler = async () => {
    await update()

    if (success === 200) {
      await fetch()
      // do some checks and if ok route
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }

  return null
}
```

The `await` keyword forces the function to block until the function call is finished.

Comment: Cool! works well. Thank you!